# gaze estimation from an image of an eye

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, human-computer-interface, eye-tracking

I've been able to detect pupil and the eye corners accurately so far. 
You can see a few snaps i uploaded in my answer to my own question here:

[Performing stable eye corner detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645871/how-to-perform-stable-eye-corner-detection)

Here's what i've done so far.
I calibrated the gaze of the user by looking at TLCP, TRCP and BLCP
where

```
CP = calibration point; a screen point used for calibration
B = bottom
T = top
L= left
R = right
gaze_width = TRCP.x - TLCP.x

gaze_height = BLCP.y- TLCP.y
```

And the corresponding gaze points i get by looking at those CPs are called GPs

calculation of a gaze point GP:

I subtract the TLGP's ordinates' values from the current pupil center's location, because the gaze point has to fall in the hypothetical rectangle whose 
i hope you understand it, its really very simple.

I've linearly mapped the gaze points calculated from pupil center's location to screen points using a basic scaling system where the scales are calculated as follows:

```
scaleX = screen_width/gaze_width
scaleY = screen_height/gaze_height
```

And for any gaze point P(x,y) i calculate the corresponding screen point Q(m,n) as:

```
m = scaleX*x
n = scaleY*y
```

But the problem is, after even almost perfect pupil detection (almost because in poor lighting it gives false positives. But i intend to put that under limitations because i can't work on it, i don't have enough time), i'm still getting poor gaze width and gaze height.

Here's a test run log:

```
DO_CAL= True

Gaze Parameters:

TLGP = (38, 26) | TRGP = (20, 22) | BLGP = (39, 33)
screen height = 768 screen width = 1366

gaze height = 7 gaze width = 18

scales: X = 75.8888888889 | Y = 109.714285714
Thing on = True

Gaze point = (5, 3)
Screen point: (987, 329)

Gaze point = (5, 3)
Screen point: (987, 329)

Gaze point = (7, 5)
Screen point: (835, 549)

Thing on = False

TLGP = (37, 24) | TRGP = (22, 22) | BLGP = (35, 29)
screen height = 768 screen width = 1366

gaze height = 5 gaze width = 15
scales: X = 91.0666666667 | Y = 153.6
Thing on = True

Gaze point = (12, 3)
Screen point: (1093, 461)

Gaze point = (12, 3)
Screen point: (1093, 461)

ESC pressed
```

Just look at the gaze points and their corresponding gaze-detected screen points (under them).
The vast differences in x,y ordinates' values is bugging me nuts.
Monday is the final presentation.

After this approach, i theorized another one where in:

Calibration is done as in the first method. I would detect the motion of the gaze, and its direction. Say, given any two points of pupil center’s location, P and Q, where P is the first gaze point, Q is the second, then we calculate the direction and length of the line PQ.
[image: Push method for gaze estimation]

Let’s assume that the length of this line segment is L. We then scale L to screen
proportions, say L is D in screen scale, and given the direction of gaze movement, we
move the cursor on the screen from its last point of rest, say R, D distance, to a new point S which will be calculated as the end point of the line segment whose length is D, and starting point S. The figurative representation is given in the figure. Thus basically, i don't map any gaze data to screen point, i basically track the gaze, and convert it into a "push" to be applied to the cursor on the screen.
But i haven't implemented it yet. Because it actually doesn't map the gaze to screen co-ordinates, and thus might be erroneous. Motivations for this theory were derived from the eViacam project on sourceforge - they basically track your face, and move the mouse accordingly. In calibration they just calculate how much your face moves along the axes.

**Bottom line**: So if any of you have any ideas of how to detect a user's gaze from a perfectly processed eye image - **one with a detected pupil center and eye corners**, please do tell! I've got just about a day, and i know its late, but i just need any magical idea that can help me.

Answer (score 6):

This is not an answer, but it is impossible to post as a comment. I'll delete it after your answer.

Are you sure you have all the necessary parameters?

Consider the following diagram:

[image]

If your camera detects the corners and pupil at {K, J, Q} , how can you distinguish from another triple {F, E, O}? Note that the measures are the same, but the gaze directions, represnted by the black arrows are completely different.

Note: the two black and the red lines were drawn from a single camera point, placed outside the visible region.

Comment: firstly, i'm using frontal face cascades for face detection, so eye_a eye will not be detected.
secondly, i get different gaze points by tracking the pupil center with respect to the eye corners. Actually up till now i've just used the image origin as the reference point, but do get the drift. 
The limitation that the user isn't supposed to move his head after he calibrated from a particular position, can't allow to have two different view points, even if they are from a frontal face (ie., similar to eye_b but towards left or right of it).The user will have to gaze from the same head position

Comment: Great drawing! Which program did you use?