# Implement Gaze estimation using STASM facial co-ordinates

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, face-detection

I need to do Gaze estimation using Opencv. I am using the [STASM](http://www.milbo.users.sonic.net/stasm/) to find the facial landmarks. And the below is the image.

[image: face]

With these available landmarks (eyes, nose, mouth)  how can I calculate the gaze estimation.

Comment: Can any one help me as i am not from image processing background?

Comment: There is one more SO question about gaze estimation from any image of eye , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365087/gaze-estimation-from-an-image-of-an-eye?rq=1 . I hope its helpfull :)