# Retrieve gaze coordinate on screen

Tags: c#, algorithm, opencv, image-processing, eye-tracking

I am implementing an eye tracker using emgucv (openCV C# wrapper), So far i was able to detect iris center and eye corner accurately.

As the next step i want to get the screen coordinate where user is focusing (also known as gaze point),As a beginner to image processing , i am completely unaware of gaze mapping and gaze estimation.

I would be thankful , if you provide any code snippets or algoritms to perform gaze mapping to retrieve gaze coordinate on screen .

Thanks in advance

Comment: May be this will help you..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10365087/gaze-estimation-from-an-image-of-an-eye?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

If you want to research the field in more depth, there's this interesting piece of research called "EyeTab: Model-based gaze estimation on unmodified tablet computers". It might have some of the information you want, or at least help you understand the field more.

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/rainbow/projects/eyetab/

(also [GitHub](http://github.com/errollw/EyeTab))